# Angular2 form "required" binding - validation not performed

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have problems with binding a dynamic "required" to an input. The input is always invalid and does not interact with the required attribute. Please have a look at my [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IFxH7XVtBKB3KKkP6uSA?p=preview).
May be I'm missing something?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <form #heroForm="ngForm">
    Set Required <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="req">
    <input #inp ngControl="something" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" [required]="req" #spy><br>
    required: {{req}}<br>
    required attribute: {{!!spy.attributes.getNamedItem("required")}}<br>
    classes: {{spy.className}}<br>
  </form>
  `
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `required` need to be added statically otherwise Angular won't initialize the validator

```
<input #inp ngControl="something" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" required #spy><br>
```

This is planned to be changed.

Comment: I haven't yet found the issue but I know there is one.